# Is there any mention by our sages of blessed memory of great centers of Jewish learning in Central Asia?

Tags: rabbis, synagogue

Is there any mention by our sages of blessed memory of great centers of Jewish learning in Central Asia: Iran Azerbaijan, Turkmenistan, Uzbekistan, Kazakhstan, Tajikistan, Kyrgyzstan, Afghanistan, Pakistan, Xinjiang, Caucasus area, Armenia, Georgia.

Comment: By Xinjiang, I presume you're referring to the outpost established by Solomon and the historically documented Jews of Kaifeng?

Comment: @Isaac Kotlicky the OP is probably referring to this Xinjiang: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinjiang

Comment: @Halloween I was specifically trying to determine why that region was singled out.

Comment: relevant info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_China